# easyPieChart загрузка на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы этот скрипт начинал работать только тогда, когда пользователь докрутил скролл до его местоположения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так понимаю для красоты, чтобы все двигалось когда пользователь увидит. 
Надо определять что пользователь видит и запускать/сдвигать/анимировать т.п.
Либо плагинами либо к примеру так

```
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
   if (($(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= $('#footer').position().top) {
      alert('easyPieChart')
   }
});
```

Заработает на текущей страница, когда будет виден футер :) Код грязный, только для примера.